# Terminology on Data Alignment in Computer Systems

Tags: architecture

I was reading about data alignment and I get what it is and all. But I read this "A word or doubleword operand that crosses a 4-byte boundary or a quadword
operand that crosses an 8-byte boundary is considered unaligned and requires two separate
memory bus cycles to access it", and all I'm really trying to understand here is the terminology he uses (I'm not a native speaker). I don't understand what he means when he says "that crosses an n-byte boundary". What is a boundary and what does he mean when he says "Crosses". Thanks so much for the patience.

I am expecting it to mean that the address needs to be alligned in multiples of 4 or 8 respectively.